# Is it possible to parse output of MongoDB query as JSON document?

Tags: json, mongodb, perl

First of all - I cannot use perl MongoDB driver, so I'm interacting with MongoDB via `IPC::Run`. Now I'd like to get output from MongoDB as a hash ref.
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use Try::Tiny;
use IPC::Run 'run';
use Data::Dumper;

my @cmd = ('/opt/mongo/bin/mongo', '127.0.0.1:27117/service_discovery', '--quiet', '-u', 'test', '-p', 'test', '--eval', 'db.sit.find().forEach(function(x){printjson(x)})');
my $out;
run \@cmd, '>>', \$out;
my $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;
my $dec = try {my $output = $coder->decode($out)} catch {undef};
print Dumper (\%$dec);
```

It is not working now, `%$dec` is empty.
Here is the output of MongoDB query (value of `$out`):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5696787eb8e5e87534777c82"),
    "hostname" : "lab7n1",
    "services" : [
            {
                    "port" : 9000,
                    "name" : "ss-rest"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 9001,
                    "name" : "ss-rest"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 8060,
                    "name" : "websockets"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 8061,
                    "name" : "websockets"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56967ab2b8e5e87534777c83"),
    "hostname" : "lab7n2",
    "services" : [
            {
                    "port" : 8030,
                    "name" : "cloud-rest for batch"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 8031,
                    "name" : "cloud-rest for batch"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 8010,
                    "name" : "cloud-rest for bespoke"
            },
            {
                    "port" : 8011,
                    "name" : "cloud-rest for bespoke"
            }
    ]
}
```

What should I do to make parser treat this output as legitimate JSON?

Comment: [Incremental parsing](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#INCREMENTAL-PARSING) is what you want, but those literal `ObjectId(...)` bits are going to be problematic.

Comment: Can you speak REST to mongo like you can Elasticsearch? That might be the answer here. https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/ Then you'll probably _have_ to get valid JSON out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Matt i used `incr_parse` method and omitted `_id` field in output.